# JS/PHP checkbox name

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

I have a question currently this:

```
function addNameCheckBox(name) {
    var html = "<div class='checkboxBlock'><label for='check_" + name + "'>" + name + ":</label><input type='checkbox' name='check_" + name + "' id='check_" + name + "' class='Stuff' /></div>";
    $("#nameCheckboxContainer").append(html);
}
```

Adds a checkbox when clicking something but instead of name=' " name" ' blabla I want the values to be like $ploegnaam[] so I can fetch them for a post how would I do that?

The output of the name= now the names that are fetched from an ajax post.

I just want it simple to be something like $ploegnaam[] althou I google'd and tried it didnt work out.

Comment: Please more clear, what you want to do? Are you want to fetch name value or what?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to fetch the names with $naam = $POST_['ploegnaam'] or something so I can add them into the DB

Comment: yes then what is the problem in your code? just tell me

Comment: How will I fetch the values ?

Comment: Dont I need to set name='ploegnaam[]' and value='' ? or did I misunderstood something...

Comment: And `$name = $_POST['check_whateverYourNameIs']` doesn't work? You already have the name specified, so what's stopping you?

Comment: That every value has a different name how would I dynamicly check that?

Answer (score 1):

You can append square brackets to your name, if you want to retrieve the values as an array in PHP:

```
<input name="foo[]" type="text" value="input1" />
<input name="foo[]" type="text" value="input2" />
```

and in php:

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST['foo']); ?>
```

It returns an array:

```
array(
   0 => 'input1',
   1 => 'input2'
)
```

Comment: Thank god someone who understand what I want

Comment: To be fair, you asked the question in a rather awkward way.

Comment: Thats fair, I just wanted to fetch the values but since check_whateverthenameis after check_ the name can be anything so thats why I asked.

Comment: yes your asking way is not correct @Tredgy. Take care in future